# Swift - Timeout with for-in iterations on large arrays when altering the Array

Tags: swift, swift2

Good morning all!

I am struggling to 'optimise' this code so that it can iterate larger quantities of Ints. I use Swift 3.0 but this compiler runs 2.0 therefore cannot use .components on Strings etc.

The code is set out as first line of Ints (n, k, q) as a String and then a second line of Ints as a String with n amount of Ints.
It then asks q amount of queries each being an Int requesting the element of that Int index from the second line Array to be printed.

My code times out when it comes to the large Ints (example: 100000 100000 500)

Any improvements or guidance would be appreciated to avoid timeout.

```
var x = readLine()!.characters.split { $0 == " " }.map { Int(String($0))! }
var y = readLine()!.characters.split { $0 == " " }.map { Int(String($0))! }

var n = x[0]
var k = x[1]
var q = x[2]

for _ in 0..<k {
    y.insert(y[n-1], at: y.startIndex)
    y.remove(at: n)
}

for _ in 0..<q {
    var i = Int(readLine()!)!
    print(y[i])
}
```

Comment: add code snippets only in HTML, CSS, PHP or JS questions, they are not needed for siwft

Comment: This looks like a programming contest where you have to "rotate" array entries. The real challenge is to find a solution where you *don't* have to modify the array  at all.

Comment: Thanks for the replies both and sorry RE code snippets...first post so apologies. - Thanks Martin - essentially I need an algorithm that just moves the counter rather than the actual array? Only question is - it then queries what is at a certain index? Therefore if I wasn't modifying the array, would the index requested still be the same regardless? Racking my brains here haha

Comment: @paulbartholomew: Well, that's what a challenge is for :) – But it isn't too difficult. If you try it with paper and pencil for a short array then you should figure out the general method quickly!

Comment: Haha of course! That is what I think I will do...appreciate your help Martin - thank you! Hopefully I will get there eventually. I only started programming as a new years resolution with Swift and I LOVE it! Even when I want to pull my hair out...its a good kind of pull my hair out